# How to efficiently store records as Ember query parameters

Tags: ember.js, query-string, ember-query-params

Background: The user can filter a list based on tags, every tag is an Ember Data model. The selected filtering tags should be stored in the URL via query parameters. I also want to display the selected tags in the interface.

What's the best way to go about this?

I'm pretty sure I only want to store the IDs, but if I do this I have to maintain a separate variable / computed property where I store the actual record of the ID which comes from the query parameters. This kind of duplication seems wrong to me.

Apart from this issue I don't know if I should use an array query parameter or build an comma separated string of the IDs. If I do the former I end up with ugly URLs like `?tags=%5B"3"%5D`. But doing the later means doing even more work.

So what's your approach to this kind of problem? I hope I'm missing something obvious that doesn't have so many downsides :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy!

1. Find out which non-alphanumeric characters are not getting encoded in URLs. Using [this tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), I found these characters: `~!*()_-.`
2. Pick one character that is not used in your tag names. Let's say it's `*`. Use it as a delimiter.
3. Use tag names for tag ids. Or at least enforce unique tag names.

Then you've got a nice readable query:

```
?tags=foo*bar*baz&search=quux
```

To implement custom query param serialization/deserialization, do this:

```
Ember.Route.reopen({
  serializeQueryParam: function(value, urlKey, defaultValueType) {
    if (defaultValueType === 'array') {
      return `${value.join('*')}`;
    }
    return this._super(...arguments);
  },

  deserializeQueryParam: function(value, urlKey, defaultValueType) {
    if (defaultValueType === 'array') {
      return value.split('*');
    }
    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

Demo: [app](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lihisu/2), [code](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lihisu/2/edit?html,js).

If you *must* use numeric tag ids in query params (for example, your tag names aren't unique), then you need some more customization: [app](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lihisu/3/), [code](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lihisu/3/edit?html,js).

Comment: Thanks for your great answer Andrey! You really understood what I was after :) I'm using your approach in my application now, thanks again.

Heads up: Your examples seem to be broken in Chrome on my computer? Something with ES6 syntax I assume, maybe you have some addon installed on your computer? Just wanted to point that out for the future.

Comment: You mean an example app is broken? Both of them? I can run them fine in Chrome, JSBin should take care of transpiling.